# I am receiving an error when trying to set up XAMPP with Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, ftp, xampp

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. I have installed XAMPP and can get it to run. I am able to open the dashboard and find the how to page. So I know that it is installed.

I am trying make it so that I am able to test the website that I am developing without being on the internet. That is why I am using XAMPP. I have FileZilla installed and it has been updated.

I have been following the steps on the how to from XAMPP for configuring ftp access. I was able to add the group but I am not able to change ownership. I use

`usermod -a -G ftp username`

where username is my actual username but I get this:

```
usermod: permission denied

usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later
```

Because of this I am not able to add any files to the htdocs folder. So now I am not able to test my site offline.

I was using Windows and XAMPP before with Dreamweaver. It was working. But I am a point where Dreamweaver is making my mad and I don't want to use it anymore. Plus I detest Windows.

Please help. I need this running. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `sudo` Mind that xampp is not worth it; it is not really usable for a production server if you want to go there. Please use our native LAMP setup. It is preconfigured for Linux.

Comment: I looked into lampp already and it is great for a server but I am just looking to test a website as I am building it. I do not always have access to the internet and need to be able to see how it looks without everybody in the world seeing how it looks. It worked.     I think. I am able to process the change of ownership of the htdocs file to me but the problem is now that I am not able to add any files to the folder.

Comment: I am using FileZila to try to add files to the htdocs folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to fix the question I asked. It was answered by Rinzwind. Thank you for helping Rinzwind.

```
You need to use sudo Mind that xampp is not worth it; it is not really usable for a production server if you want to go there. Please use our native LAMP setup. It is preconfigured for Linux.
```